# “joi.validate is not a function” Error Question

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, joi

exports.localLogin = async (ctx) => {

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    email: Joi.string().email().required(),
    password: Joi.string().required()
});

const result = Joi.validate(ctx.request.body, schema);

if(result.error) {
    ctx.status = 400; // Bad Request
    return;
}

const { email, password } = ctx.request.body; 

let account = null;
try {
  
    account = await Account.findByEmail(email);
} catch (e) {
    ctx.throw(500, e);
}

if(!account || !account.validatePassword(password)) {

    ctx.status = 403; // Forbidden
    return;
}

ctx.body = account.profile;
```

};

I can't resolve “joi.validate is not a function” Error.Through googling, i try

const validation= Joi.schema(ctx.request.body);

but i couldn't solve the problem. help me please

Answer (score 0):

Please check you JOI version. Because it has substantial addons from the version over 16.
When i had the same issue. I have resolved it by rephrasing

> Joi.validate(ctx.request.body, schema) with
> schema.validate(ctx.request.body)